# Powershell/CMD is not recognizing PATH variable

Tags: powershell, cmd, environment-variables, windows-11

Windows 11/ Powershell 7.2.1

I've added the following variables to user PATH and system PATH.
`C:\Program Files\rclone\rclone-v1.57.0-windows-amd64\rclone.exe`

When I try to run `rclone` from Powershell or cmd I get the following message:

> PS C:\Windows\System32> rclone rclone: The term 'rclone' is not
> recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
> verify that the path is correct and try again.

Sucessfully ran `refreshenv` and just to be sure I restarted Windows.
After running `$env:path -split ";"` I can see `C:\Program Files\rclone\rclone-v1.57.0-windows-amd64\rclone.exe` is set correctly.

I can run `rclone` from within the program folder I get this notice.

> PS C:\Program Files\rclone\rclone-v1.57.0-windows-amd64> rclone
> rclone: The term 'rclone' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of
> the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
> and try again.
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: The command rclone was not found, but does
> exist in the current location. PowerShell does not load commands from
> the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead
> type: ".\rclone". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more
> details.

After setting rclone on PATH it still isn't "seen", what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the directory containing the rclone.exe not the path of the executable. You should add **C:\Program Files\rclone\rclone-v1.57.0-windows-amd64** to the PATH enveronement  not **C:\Program Files\rclone\rclone-v1.57.0-windows-amd64\rclone.exe**

Comment: Thanks @BETOMBO! Just got back from reading an article mentioning exactly that. Best way of learning is through mistakes! 