# Why is powershell not recognizing spyder command despite changing path variables?

Tags: python, powershell, pip, spyder

I installed python from the windows store which came with python version 3.11.6, pip, and Idle IDE. Idle and pip are working fine. I then installed spyder using the command `pip install spyder` which successfully installed Spyder. However, the command `spyder` is not recognized. I also tried adding the path to spyder.exe to environment variables, which didn't work. I then uninstalled spyder using `pip uninstall spyder`, which was successful, and then tried installing Spyder via `pip3 install spyder` and the command `spyder` was still not recognized by powershell despite adding the appropriate path variables.

`pip` is able to recognize Spyder and install/uninstall it without an error, but the command `spyder` is not recognized.

**P.S.** If I input the exact path to spyder.exe, spyder does launch and work properly. I don't want to use conda because managing packages separately from pip and conda becomes a little tedious.

I tried the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70469614/18907674) question, and this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Without additional information, your problem cannot be diagnosed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414006/45375) contains detailed troubleshooting steps for problems related to locating executables via the `PATH` environment variable. If they help you solve your problem, we can close your question as a duplicate. If you've tried everything there and it still doesn't work, please provide more information.

Comment: @mklement0 I was not able to follow through the question which seemed to talk about different issues. I removed all the added paths, restarted the PC, and ran `pip install spyder` again. This time, for some reason, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: While the linked _question_ was about a different, _specific_ scenario, its accepted _answer_ tries to provide a _general_ troubleshooting guide with respect to `PATH` issues. Rebooting is suggested as _one_ possible remedy - albeit _after_ installation. Nevertheless, since that helped in your case, I'll mark your question as a duplicate. If you've discovered a - reproducible - scenario _not_ covered by the linked post, let us know, and we can revisit.